# Tuckey urlrewrite, How to check is parameter with specified name exists?

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Seems the following configuration does not work

```
<rule>
    <condition type="parameter" name="direct" operator="notequal"></condition>
    <from>^/payment.html$</from>
    <set name="google-analytics-uri">/shop/payment-direct</set>
</rule>
```

Enter url: _http://somesite.com/payment.html?direct=value
As result 'google-analytics-uri' is empty.

Answer (score 2):

found solution(after debugging library sources:)

```
<rule>
    <condition type="parameter" name="direct" operator="notequal">^$</condition>
    <from>^/payment.html$</from>
    <set name="google-analytics-uri">/shop/payment-direct</set>
</rule>
```

Comment: There's an easier way: `<condition type="parameter" name="direct" operator="equal"/>` matches if the parameter exists, while `<condition type="parameter" name="direct" operator="notequal"/>` matches if the parameter doesn't exist. This is slightly counter-intuitive, but for a reason I don't know the library defines an empty pattern as a test for whether the value defined in the condition (in this case the parameter value) exists at all. "notequal" just functions like a boolean "not" to the result of that evaluation.